# How to control the fade speed with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I control the FadeOut animation speed:

```
setTimeout(fade_out, 5000);

function fade_out() {
    $("#LoadingGIF").fadeOut().empty();
}
```

Comment: Did you try reading [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)?

Comment: Yes, and it is hard to make sense of. I don't really know a lot of jquery and when it does the same thing I am doing but a different way, it messes me up and I can't figure it out. I will get it sooner or later, still learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#LoadingGIF').fadeOut('slow' /* 400 (milliseconds) , fast, etc. */);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the speed in the fadeOut function

```
.fadeOut(1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to empty the element after fading it  you can use the callback parameter

```
$LoadingGIF=$("#LoadingGIF");
$LoadingGIF.fadeOut(5000,function(){
  $LoadingGIF.empty();
});
```